# Create standalone MATLAB CGI to run on IIS

Tags: matlab, iis

I am trying to deploy a matlab example application on the IIS 7.5. 
I am following these instructions given here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-30REEY/

However When I submit the form on the server, It just asks if I want to save the file .exe file (screenshot attached below).

[image]
I have downloaded the sample application from the above URL, and just compiled it using the command: `mcc -m mycgimagic.m`

I have tried to check the folder permissions on IIS. What else I should check to find the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the webserver, in which your exe is not treated as a cgi but as a "normal" file.
Hence the webserver offers the file for download, instead of executing it.

I haven't used iis, but this is what I googled:

http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2010/04/04/how-to-run-a-cgi-program-under-iis-7-0-or-iis-7-5.aspx